# Confusion while using the uncertainty principle

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle

A question asks to estimate the energy of a neutron, if the neutron is composed of a proton and electron by using the uncertainty principle.

The basic idea is to let $x \approx 1$ fm and calculate $\Delta p_x$ using: $$\Delta x \cdot \Delta p_x \geq \dfrac{\hbar}{2}$$

However, shouldn't the value of $\Delta p_x$, calculated using this expression, give the uncertainty of the momentum? Not the actual value if momentum of the electron, right? In fact, the momentum could still be 0.

So how to calculate the energy uncertainty, $\Delta E$?